# Lazy load: images being loaded/revealed at once take a while

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, lazy-loading

I lazy load my images using intersection observer. This works fine, but I have a slider that reveals multiple images at once - in other words, a bunch of images are being loaded simultaneously on reveal.

My problem is, these image kind of need a while to load and kind of have the same loading time. F.e. when one image needs 5 seconds, all the others do as well.

How so? How come this behavior?

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    elem.srcset = this.url;
    observer.unobserve(elem);
    observer.disconnect();
  }
}, {threshold: 0, rootMargin: '100px'});
observer.observe(elem);
```

Comment: If an image take that long to load are your image not way to large?

Comment: @Baracuda078 They are all about 30kb

Comment: That is already indeed very small. And without the observer they load fast?

Comment: @Baracuda078 Yes, they solely take a while to load when a bunch of images are being revealed having to load them at once.